# Incident number with Vlookup return grouped with ROW () in single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an incident column in a log. I have the following formula in the table column cell (is a table, so already increments):

```
=VLOOKUP(WHSELocation,Hidden!$J$2:$K$33,2,FALSE),ROW()
```

Of course this is coming back in error.

The idea is it is looking in 'WHSE Location" a name, it matches with it's number, and then I want it grouped with the row number.

Example: `39121, 39122 ...` or even better `3912-1, 3912-2 ...`

This would be awesome to not only learn but use for future projects.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(WHSELocation,Hidden!$J$2:$K$33,2,FALSE)&"-"&ROW()` ?

Comment: Dangit!  I knew it was something as simple as that.  Thank you!!!